# Is there an equivalent to MySecureShell for Centos?

Tags: centos, sftp, chroot

I have some issue to install MySecureShell on CentOS 5.4 because I want to use Yum to install it (for maintainability).
I get this error :

```
yum install mysecureshell
Error: Missing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by package mysecureshell-1.20-1.x86_64 (mysecureshell)
```

I assume that the issue is that openSSL shipped with CentOS 5.4 is too old...

I don't want to install everything manually so I would like to know if there is an equivalent to MySecureShell which would work with CentOS 5.4.

Thanks!

---

UPDATE :

OpenSSL is correctly installed. However only libcrypto.so.6 is available on my system (due to an old OpenSSL version available in the CentOS repo)

I am using a Fedora 12 repository for MySecureShell

Answer (score 1):

This is expected when trying to install Fedora apps directly in CentOS.  This results from Fedora having more up to date apps and libraries.

You have a few of choices:

1. Install openssl from Fedora and hope it doesn't crash other ssl using apps - NOT RECOMMENDED!
2. Grab the source rpm from Fedora and build your own package using CentOS's current libraries.
3. Check one of the [CentOS 3rd party repo's](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) and see if mysecureshell is available through one of them.
4. Check [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/) or one of its cousins and see if you can get an rpm through them.

If you do find an RPM, make sure it matches your CentOS architecture (32 bit, 64 bit, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There is no MySecureShell in base or updates repo, but it has it's own repo, check here:
http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net/en/installpak.html#question3

Just add the repo file /etc/yum.repos.d/mysecureshell.repo

```
[mysecureshell]
name=MySecureShell
baseurl=http://mysecureshell.free.fr/repository/index.php/centos/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Then:

```
yum install mysecureshell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing a package via yum against a CentOS repository, any dependencies should be available within the distribution.

It seems like you may not have the 64 bit version of openssl installed.

You can install the openssl package via yum.

**Edit 1**

Using the Fedora package repository on CentOS is a bad idea.  You're going to consistently encounter dependency and compatibility issues.

If you're unable to find a mysecureshell CentOS package that someone else built on the Internet, you could use the source rpm to build your own package or compile from source.  If you do find a precompiled package, it will need to be built for your major version and architecture of CentOS.

Comment: I am using a Fedora 12 repo. this is why there is dependencies issues...

OpenSSL is correctly installed on my system.